# How to bind/unbind click to prevent animate's queue chaos?

Tags: jquery, queue, jquery-animate, bind, unbind

This one won't work. Animation queue end up in a chaos. What did I'm wrong? Help please.

```
$button.bind('click',showHideFavourites);

function showHideFavourites() {
    if ($favContent.css('opacity') == 1) { 
        hideFavourites(); 
    } else { 
        showFavourites(); 
    }
}

function hideFavourites() { 
    $button.unbind('click');

    $favContent.animate({'opacity':'0'},250,function() { 
        $favourites.animate({'height':0},{queue:false,duration:250,easing:'easeInOutQuad',complete:function() {
            $button.text(showFav);

            $button.bind('click',showFavourites);
        }});
    });
}

function showFavourites() {
    $button.unbind('click');

    $favourites.animate({'height':fl_openHeight},{queue:false,duration:250,easing:'easeInOutQuad',complete:function() {
        $favContent.animate({'opacity':'1'},250);
        $button.text(hideFav);

        $button.bind('click',hideFavourites);   
        });
    }});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$button.on('click', function() {
    $favContent.css('opacity') == 1) ? hideFavourites() : showFavourites(); 
});

function hideFavourites() { 
    $favContent.stop(true, true).animate({'opacity':'0'},250,function() { 
        $favourites.stop(true, true).animate({'height':0}, 250, 'easeInOutQuad', function() {
            $button.text(showFav);
        });
    });
}

function showFavourites() {
    $favourites.stop(true, true).animate({'height':fl_openHeight}, 250 'easeInOutQuad' function() {
        $button.text(hideFav);
        $favContent.stop(true, true).animate({'opacity':'1'},250);
     });
}
```

If your trying to animate height and opacity at the same time you should drop the chaining functions as well, i did'nt as I was'nt sure what the noqeue was for?

Comment: Thank you. What's about the `.on`, I never heard about that. First I think that should be `.one`, but this makes no sense in that case. So I tested it with `.on` and it does the thing as a matter of fact, but the queue problem is still there, when I click the button quickly two or three times.

Comment: .on() is new, you can still use .click(), but I used on as it replaces bind, live, click etc. makes it easier not having to choose one. The problem with the animation qeue building up could probably be resolved with .stop(); see the jQuery site for more information, but stop() stops the animation, and stop(true) clears the qeue, while stop(true, true) clears the qeue and takes the animation directly to the end. I've added some stops to the example to show how it's done, but you will usually have to experiment a little to get it right for you particular use.